# Update hibernate sequences to generate unique ids

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have got a table which has whereby id (which is the primary key) is generated as below:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name="idGen")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "idGen")
private Long id = -1L;
```

I had insert records manually into this database to resolve a issue. But now when the application restarted the database doesn't seem to recognise the new ids that have been manually inserted and is regenerating same ids again.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `GenerationType.TABLE` the current id is stored in a table. The name of the table is probably configured somewhere, with `idGen` as identifier. You would probably have to update this table to reflect the id's you assigned manually. You might also have to restart your application, as it might have cached the next few id's to be assigned.

That being said, using `GenerationType.TABLE` is not recommended. It uses pessimistic locks, and might slow down your application.

Instead, you should use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` if your database supports it. If you want something simple, that also works when inserting rows directly in the database, you can use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, which relies on autonumbering of the column in the database. Although simple, it's not the most performant. But probably nothing dramatic if the amount of inserts is relatively low.

Comment: I managed to find the table which is generating the sequence. Since no table name was given it was using hibernate_sequences table. So if the sequence_next_hi_value is currently 5,  should be I running following query `update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = 6 where sequence_next_hi_value = 5 and sequence_name = 'userTable'` and then re-start the system ??